# child image in visiblity widget flutter

Tags: flutter

i aim to display an image if my variable bool is true else i don't diplay it for that i used the widget visiblity . but it does not work  how can fix it ?

```
Visibility(
            visible: widget.isThereIcon,
            child: const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
              child: Image.asset(
                'images/OK.png',
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .27,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .27,
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure `widget.isThereIcon` is bool variable

And set the value to **true** if you want to show the image and **false** if you want to hide it

use statefullWidget and your UI code:

```
       Scaffold(
          body: Column(
            children: [
              Visibility(
                visible: widget.isThereIcon,
                child: const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                  child: Image.asset(
                    'images/OK.png',
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .27,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .27,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    widget.isThereIcon = !widget.isThereIcon;
                    //if widget.isThereIcon == true => widget.isThereIcon = false
                    //if widget.isThereIcon == false => widget.isThereIcon = true
                  });
                },
                child: Text("show image"),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

is it stateless or statefull ? show how do you change state of visibility?
probably you forgot about setState

```
setState((){
      widget.isThereIcon = true;
});
```

or

```
setState((){
      widget.isThereIcon = false;
});
```